# Может ли react-router обрабатывать редирект с сервера?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

Имеется обработчик на сервере:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/login');
});
```

Как заставить react-router обрабатывать редирект на сервере

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Header/Header'));
const RegistrationForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/RegistrationForm/RegistrationForm'));
const LogonForm = React.lazy(() => import('./Components/Forms/LogonForm/LogonForm'));
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Header />
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={ LogonForm } />
                    <Route exact path="/registration" component={ RegistrationForm } />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
```

То есть после запроса на сервер нам рендерился компонент LogonForm

Answer (score 0):

Настройте маршруты и шаблоны на сервере так, чтобы на **любой запрос** возвращалась страница, на которой запускается ваш `App`. Тогда роутер отработает правильно. Иначе сервер может вернуть 404, если в реальности страницы не существует.